# Chain of Responsibility pattern for updating coordinates of moving objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns

`PrimaryCoordinates` are the coordinates in meters.  `SecondaryCoordinates` are the coordinates in decimeters, with the origin located at
the primary coordinates.  `TertiaryCoordinates` are the coordinates in cm, with the origin at the secondary coordinates.  The `Position` of an object, depending on its size, could have all three cooordinate types.  So let's say that a `Person` is holding a `Gun`, which contains `Bullet`s.  As the person moves, the gun and bullets will move with him.  The bullets will ask the gun for the new coordinates, which in turn will ask the person for the new coordinates.  Due to this chain, and the complexity of having the three coordinate systems for `Position`, I have decided to use the Chain of Responsibility to get the new `Position` of the gun and bullets as the person moves (or if the gun alone moves).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

struct Coordinates {
    int x, y, z;
    Coordinates (int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) { }
    bool operator== (const Coordinates& other) const { return x == other.x && y == other.y && z == other.z; }
    bool operator!= (const Coordinates& other) const { return !(*this == other); } 
    void print (std::ostream& os = std::cout) const {os << "(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")\n";}    
};

struct PrimaryCoordinates : Coordinates {  // Coordinates in meters.
    using Coordinates::Coordinates;
} nonesuch = {-1,-1,-1};

struct SecondaryCoordinates : Coordinates {  // Coordinates in decimeters, with the origin specified by PrimaryCoordinates.
    using Coordinates::Coordinates;
} s_nonesuch = {-1,-1,-1};

struct TertiaryCoordinates : Coordinates {  // Coordinates in centimeters, with the origin specified by SecondaryCoordinates.
    using Coordinates::Coordinates;
} t_nonesuch = {-1,-1,-1};

struct Position {
    PrimaryCoordinates primaryCoordinates;
    SecondaryCoordinates secondaryCoordinates;
    TertiaryCoordinates tertiaryCoordinates;
    Position (const PrimaryCoordinates& p = nonesuch, const SecondaryCoordinates& s = s_nonesuch, TertiaryCoordinates t = t_nonesuch) : primaryCoordinates(p), secondaryCoordinates(s), tertiaryCoordinates(t) { }
    void print (std::ostream& os = std::cout) const {
        os << "Primary Coordinates = ";  primaryCoordinates.print(os);
        if (secondaryCoordinates != s_nonesuch) {
            os << "Secondary Coordinates = ";  secondaryCoordinates.print(os);
        }
        if (tertiaryCoordinates != t_nonesuch) {
            os << "Tertiary Coordinates = ";  tertiaryCoordinates.print(os);
        }
    }
};

class Entity {
    Position position;
public:
    virtual ~Entity() = default;
    PrimaryCoordinates getPrimaryCoordinates() const { return position.primaryCoordinates; }
    void setPrimaryCoordinates (const PrimaryCoordinates& p) { position.primaryCoordinates = p; }
    void setPrimaryCoordinates (int x, int y, int z = 0) { position.primaryCoordinates = {x, y, z}; }
    void setSecondaryCoordinates (int x, int y, int z = 0) { position.secondaryCoordinates = {x, y, z}; }
    void setTertiaryCoordinates (int x, int y, int z = 0) { position.tertiaryCoordinates = {x, y, z}; }
    void movesTo (int x, int y, int z = 0) { setPrimaryCoordinates(x, y, z); }
    virtual Position findPosition (Position&) const { return position; }
    Position getPosition() const { Position p;  return findPosition(p); }
};

class ContainableEntity : public Entity {  // A pillar, for example, is a NonContainableEntity, and thus should have no 'holder' data member.
protected:
    Entity* holder = nullptr;  // The 'next' pointer in the Chain of Responsibility pattern.
public:
    void setHolder (Entity* h) { holder = h; }  // The 'setNext()' method in the Chain of Responsibility pattern.
    virtual Position findPosition (Position& p) const override {  // The virtual 'handle()' method in the base 'Handler' class in the Chain of Responsibility pattern.  Here the ContainableEntity class is the abstact 'Handler' base class.
        if (holder)
            return holder->findPosition(p);
        p.primaryCoordinates = getPrimaryCoordinates();
        return p;
    }
};

class Item : public ContainableEntity { };

class Bullet : public Item {  // A concrete Handler class (since it is a concrete derived class of Item) that could have its own 'handle() override'.
    bool fired = false;
public:
    void hasBeenFired() { fired = true; }
    virtual Position findPosition (Position& p) const override {  // This override is the 'handle() override' of a concrete derived Handler subtype in the Chain of Responsibility pattern, calling the base class' handle() method at the end.
        if (!fired)
            p.tertiaryCoordinates = {2, 2, 2};
        else
            p.tertiaryCoordinates = {2, 2, 0};
        return ContainableEntity::findPosition(p);
    }
};

class Gun : public Item {  // A concrete Handler class (since it is a concrete derived class of Item) that could have its own 'handle() override'.
    std::list<Bullet*> bullets;
public:
    void addBullets (int amount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            Bullet* bullet = new Bullet;
            bullets.push_back (bullet);
            bullet->setHolder(this);
        }           
    }
    void print (std::ostream& os = std::cout) const {
        os << "Position of gun:\n";
        getPosition().print();
        os << "Coordinates of bullets:\n";
        for (Bullet* x : bullets) {
            os << "Bullet:\n";
            x->getPosition().print();
        }
    }
    Bullet* fire() {
        Bullet* firedBullet = bullets.back();
        firedBullet->movesTo(1000, 1000, 0);
        firedBullet->setHolder(nullptr);
        firedBullet->hasBeenFired();
        bullets.pop_back();
        return firedBullet;
    }
    virtual Position findPosition (Position& p) const override {  // This override is the 'handle() override' of a concrete derived Handler subtype in the Chain of Responsibility pattern, calling the base class' handle() method at the end.
        if (holder)
            p.secondaryCoordinates = {3, 4, 8};
        else
            p.secondaryCoordinates = {3, 4, 0};
        return ContainableEntity::findPosition(p);
    }
};

class Inventory {
private:
    class Person* holder = nullptr;
    Gun* gun = nullptr;
public:
    Inventory (Person* person) : holder(person) {}
    Person* getHolder() const {return holder;}
    void addItem (Gun*);
    void removeGun();
    Gun* getGun() const {return gun;}
    void print (std::ostream& os = std::cout) const {
        if (gun)
            gun->print(os);
    }
};

class Person : public ContainableEntity {  // A Person could be contained in a (moving) car for example, which would be his 'holder'.
private:
    std::string name;
    Inventory* inventory;
public:
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n), inventory (new Inventory(this)) {setPrimaryCoordinates(10, 20, 0);}
    std::string getName() const {return name;}
    Inventory* getInventory() const {return inventory;}
    void print (std::ostream& os = std::cout) const {
        os << "Name: " << name << "\nCoordinates: ";
        getPosition().print(os);
        inventory->print(os);
    }
    void addItem (Gun* gun) const {inventory->addItem(gun);}
    void removeGun() const {inventory->removeGun();}
    Bullet* fireGun() const {
        if (!getInventory()->getGun())
            return nullptr;
        return getInventory()->getGun()->fire();
    }
};

void Inventory::addItem (Gun* g) {
    gun = g;
    gun->setHolder(holder);
}

void Inventory::removeGun() {
    gun->setPrimaryCoordinates(holder->getPrimaryCoordinates());
    gun->setHolder(nullptr);
    gun = nullptr;
}

int main() {
    Person* bob = new Person("Bob");
    Gun* gun = new Gun;
    gun->addBullets(3);
    bob->addItem (gun);
    bob->print();
    
    std::cout << "\nBob fires his gun.\n";
    Bullet* firedBullet = bob->fireGun();
    std::cout << "Coordinates of fired bullet:\n";
    firedBullet->getPosition().print();
    
    bob->movesTo(50,40,0);
    std::cout << "\nBob has moved to ";
    bob->getPosition().print();
    bob->print();
    std::cout << "Coordinates of fired bullet:\n";
    firedBullet->getPosition().print();

    bob->removeGun();
    std::cout << "\nBob has dropped his gun.\n";
    bob->movesTo(100,200,0);
    std::cout << "\nBob has moved to ";
    bob->getPosition().print();
    bob->print();
    gun->print();
    std::cout << "Coordinates of fired bullet:\n";
    firedBullet->getPosition().print();
    
    gun->movesTo(10,20,0);
    std::cout << "\nThe gun has moved (somehow) to primary coordinates (10, 20, 0):\n";
    gun->print();
    std::cout << "Coordinates of fired bullet:\n";
    firedBullet->getPosition().print();
}
```

Output:

```
Name: Bob
Coordinates: Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Position of gun:
Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 8)
Coordinates of bullets:
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 8)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 8)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 8)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)

Bob fires his gun.
Coordinates of fired bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (1000, 1000, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 0)

Bob has moved to Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Name: Bob
Coordinates: Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Position of gun:
Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 8)
Coordinates of bullets:
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 8)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 8)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Coordinates of fired bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (1000, 1000, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 0)

Bob has dropped his gun.

Bob has moved to Primary Coordinates = (100, 200, 0)
Name: Bob
Coordinates: Primary Coordinates = (100, 200, 0)
Position of gun:
Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 0)
Coordinates of bullets:
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (50, 40, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Coordinates of fired bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (1000, 1000, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 0)

The gun has moved (somehow) to primary coordinates (10, 20, 0):
Position of gun:
Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 0)
Coordinates of bullets:
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (10, 20, 0)
Secondary Coordinates = (3, 4, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 2)
Coordinates of fired bullet:
Primary Coordinates = (1000, 1000, 0)
Tertiary Coordinates = (2, 2, 0)
```

Note however, that the coordinates of the gun and bullets are not actually updated with the correct values (as the Observer Pattern would).  But my rationale for letting that slide is that the coordinates of the gun and bullets are rarely needed, and when they are needed (including saving to txt file), the getPosition() method using
the Chain of Responsibility pattern will output the correct coordinates despite the stored values being incorrect.  The performance of the program is greatly enhanced by not constantly updating the coordinates with the Observer Pattern.  I think using the Observer Patter would be much more complex too (I will try that next and compare).

Answer (score 3):

While using a chain of responsibility is good idea here, the implementation you have chosen is not. The most important problem is that it doesn't scale. Consider adding a `Car`, and a `Person` being able to get in a car and drive. Now add a `Ferry`, and drive the `Car` onto the `Ferry`. With your approach, you would need `QuaternaryCoordinates` and `QuinaryCoordinates`, `Position` would grow, and the complexity of handling all the possible nesting levels grows exponentially.

Consider instead storing just one `Coordinate` in each entity, and if an entity is held by another entity, then the coordinate of the first entity is taken to be relative to that of the holder. So:

```
class Entity {
    Coordinate position;
    …
public:
    virtual Position getPosition() const { return position; }
    …
};

class ContainableEntity: public Entity {
    …
public:
    Position getPosition() const override {
        if (holder) {
            return holder->getPosition() + Entity::getPosition();
        } else {
            return Entity::getPosition();
        }
    }
};
```

The above assumes you added an `operator+()` to `Coordinate`, and that all coordinates use the same units.

I would also remove `findPosition()`, and not update any coordinate inside `getPosition()`. For example, when firing a bullet, just change its coordinate inside `hasBeenFired()`. That function should also be renamed to `fire()` to indicate it is an action, not a query.